# Modifying Users in Active Directory

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, automation

I have modified (to loop through many users) a script from [this MS website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156515.aspx) to add users to a group in AD but on this page doesnt tell me how to do something.

```
Const ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND = 3
Set objGroup = GetObject _
 ("LDAP://cn=Atl-Users,ou=HR,dc=NA,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")

objGroup.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND, _
 "member", Array("cn=YoungRob,ou=R&D,dc=NA,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")

objGroup.SetInfo
```

Where can I add and what is the code for checking if they already have this group and if they do skip them and just say something like `wscript.echo "yeah they got this already" + UserName`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Const ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND = 3

dn = "cn=YoungRob,ou=R&D,dc=NA,dc=fabrikam,dc=com"

isMember = False

'check regular group memberships
For Each m In objGroup.GetEx("member")
  If LCase(m) = LCase(dn) Then
    isMember = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next

'check primary group
primaryGroupID = GetObject(dn).Get("primaryGroupID")
objGroup.GetInfoEx Array("primaryGroupToken"), 0
If primaryGroupID = objGroup.Get("primaryGroupToken") Then isMember = True

If Not isMember Then objGroup.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND, "member", Array(dn)
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar I will give this a go on Monday :) ... I see your name everywhere on here you must be a great programmer/scripter ?

Comment: Just a humble sysadmin.

Comment: This is a little bit off topic but still relevant in a  way. .. in a command prompt program I.e. ping you can use /? After it to get switches and what else you can use it for..can you do this same in vbscript?

Comment: You mean for information about particular methods, properties or structures? I'm afraid not. Unlike PowerShell VBScript doesn't support type introspection, so you'll have to read the documentation and/or adopt sample scripts from other sources ([ActiveXperts](http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/) for instance have quite an extensive repository).